# Intercept special keys on a headset (hook on / hook off)

Tags: c#, c++, windows, audio, headset

I have a Logitech headset with some keys on it. But I have others with the same features from other manufacturers.

Two for the volume, one to mute the microphone. SO my question is not about volume control or muting. I am aware how to do this.

The fourth one is the one I am interested in. It is a hook on, hook off. The documentation says it is Lync compatible. But how Lync does it?

I want to intercept this key. Or better I want to handle it in my own TAPI and VoIP aware software.
But I can't see how to do that.

I used Spy++ to track system wide messages but I don't see a special window message or key created when I press the key. I also tried and expected that it has something to do with WM_APPCOMMAND where some media control keys creates extra messages when I press the stop button on my keyboard. But no avail.

I suppose that I have to use DirectPlay but where to start.

Does anyone have a solution for this.

Comment: *"But how Lync does it?"* - worth to do a research first. Or you have a more specific question to ask. Quick google shows there is [sdk](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/lync/desktop/code-samples-lync-sdk). And here is a whole [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/lync).

Comment: Any more information about htis?