# Detect Hook On Hook off on USB headsets (Jabra/Logitech and others)

Tags: c++, windows, usb

There is a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65019779/intercept-special-keys-on-a-headset-hook-on-hook-off) longer ago. I also asked the owner, but I got no answer.
So I ask the question again.

I have searched a lot of sources, in detail:

1. I found nothing in the Lync SDK about this.
2. In the DirectInput samples I can't find any special codes about "headsets", or special "keyboard" devices or messages.
3. In fact I see no Windows message at all when I use Spy++.
4. No other sample code can be found.